# How can I extract html with fscanf

Tags: c++, scanf

I have a file, each line holds a .

```
<div style="random properties" id="keyword1:string id:int">text</div>
<div style="random properties" id="keyword1:string id:int">text</div>
<div style="random properties" id="keyword2:string id:int">text</div>
<div style="random properties" id="keyword2:string id:int">text</div>
```

Can i with fscanf return a list of text and id for a matching keyword1 and keyword2?

Comment: Yes you can. But if you use an html parsing library or even a parser generator like yacc, you'd also keep your sanity.

Comment: Do you have a reason for wanting to use `fscanf` in particular? This reads a bit like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/166663)...

Comment: There are numerous existing xml parsers, tinyXml for example. You could also use regular expression (boost and c++11 standard library support them) or craft your own parser using boost spirit. Why would you stick with fscanf, which suffers from so many problems…

Comment: Well whatever solution that works, have 1000 lines i need the info from and the only thing i tried before is fscanf, i just could not get it to work. I just placed the line into fscanf and repaced text with %s and id with %d - no results.

Comment: I have c and a c compiler, not looking for setting yacc up unless its easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply read it with regex:

```
std::string s;
std::regex r( "<div style=\"[^\"]*\" id=\".*(\\d+)\">((?:(?!</div>).)*)</div>" );
while( std::getline(in, s) ) {
    std::smatch m;
    if( std::regex_match(s, m, r) ) {
        std::cout << "id = " << m.str(1) << ", text = " << m.str(2) << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "invalid pattern" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

But if you want to read more about `regex` please go to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex

Comment: Assuming this isn't a real html file and each line actually begins with <div> and ends with </div>.

Comment: You are correct, but it sounds like he/she wants a way of doing it.  A solution like the one here might work as well but not be as fragile to things like newlines in the middle of the div tags or format changes
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489522/library-recommendation-c-html-parser

Comment: @Beached He/She require a HTML parsing library to parse full HTML and there is no way and no need that someone that is not so familiar with C++ and HTML can write a parser for it, so I think this will help him/her to at least learn mighty `regex` and begin to work with it for simple parsing! But if he/she need a way to parse full HTML or format of its input might change then he/she should start using an HTML parser library